# How to close a conversation in the @assistant/conversation

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have created a cloud function to handle some logics in which i would like to close the conversation.

I have tried the following but i have got an error stating that there is no method named close in the conversation

```
conv.close('Thankyou');
```

I have checked the documentation of **[@assistant/conversation](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.0.0/classes/_conversation_conv_.conversationv3.html)** where there is no method to close a conversation

[image]

I would like to know how to close a conversation from the cloud function as well as is it possible to use the system scenes in the cloud function for example

To end a conversation in a scene we would transit to the End conversation scene. Similarly in the cloud function can we use it

```
conv.scene.next.name = 'End conversation'
```

For the custom scene which we create, it works fine but if we try to use the system scenes in the cloud function it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to transition to exit directly is to use the special "End Conversation" scene name: `actions.page.END_CONVERSATION`.

Another reasonable approach, however, would be to transition to a Scene, and the primary thing *that* Scene does is transition to ending the conversation. Since you can't transition as part of the Entry message, you'll need to create a condition that is "true".

[image: Illustration of Exit scene]

This may seem like an unnecessary hack, but this isn't as crazy as it sounds - for some Actions, it would make sense to have a common closing and cleanup process, and centralizing them in one logical place makes sense.

Comment: Thanks,I have used the actions.pages.END_CONVERSATION.  I have tried to make it centralize and close the conversation but in that case, if we create a new scene and onEnter prompt if we write our exit message then we can't see a Transition to End the conversation so in that case how do we make our action to exit from the scene.(If we don't have any intents or conditions for that scene)

Comment: I restructured the answer, making the end conversation string first, but also providing a better illustration about how to create an Exit scene.